# Using Javascript, .test and RegEx to evaluate a URL for /?s=

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test the URL `http://example.com` in a browser window for an empty search string, i.e `http://example.com/search/?s=`, but not match anything like `/search/?s=withsearchterms` that has any search terms after the `/search/?s=`, and then use an `if` statement and `.addClass` to display a div that warns that no search terms were entered.

I'm trying to use Javascript and `g.test` like below; the `RegEx` pattern is valid, according to several RegEx testers. But no luck:

```
var href = window.location.href;

var contains = /[\/?s=]+/g.test(href);

if (contains) {

$("#no-search-terms").addClass("display-block");

}
```

Is my RegEx wrong? Is my use of `test` wrong?

---

**Edit 11/29/2020**

This work, thanks to **Heo**:

```
var search = window.location.href;
var regex = /(?<=\/\?s=).*$/
    
var result=regex.exec( search )

if (result && result[0]=='') {
      
  alert("The search terms are empty.");
} else {
  alert("The search terms are not empty or no matched.");
}
```

But **miknik's** answer is much simpler with no need for regex. Works on Chrome 87, Firefox 83 and Safari 14:

```
const queries = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
if (queries.has("s") && queries.get("s").length == 0){

  alert("The search terms are empty.");
      
}
```

Comment: `[]` in regex means any of those characters, order agnostic. Maybe you mean `\/\?s=(?!testme)`? or something like that?

Comment: Thanks; I just want to match the exact `/?s=` and ignore anything that has search terms, like `/?s=searchterms` so I can display a div that warns that no search terms were entered.

Comment: May the `exec()` is a good choice for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for regex here, something like this should work fine in modern browsers:

```
const queries = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
if (queries.has("s") && queries.get("s").length == 0){
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can test if end of string contains `/?s=`:

```js
var url1 = 'https://example.com/?s=';
var url2 = 'https://example.com/?s=withsearchterms';
var regex = /\/\?s=$/;
console.log(url1 + '  ==> ' + regex.test(url1));
console.log(url2 + '  ==> ' + regex.test(url2));
```

Output:

```
https://example.com/?s=  ==> true
https://example.com/?s=withsearchterms  ==> false
```

Explanation:

- `\/\?s=` - expect `/?s=`
- `$` - trailing `$` anchors the regex at the end, e.g. preceding text must occur at the end
- thus, the test returns true if the url has no search term (you can reverse your `if` test)

Comment: Thanks! That's interesting. Real basic question: how to I evaluate for true? i.e., `search ==> regex.test(search)`

Comment: the `regex.test()` returns true or false, so you can use it directly in an `if()`

Comment: I meant, you can use as: `if(regex.test(url)) { ... }`. Any other questions? Consider accepting this answer?

Comment: Yes, because it's a match! That is why I mentioned "(you can reverse your `if` test)", e.g. test like this: `if(!regex.test(url)) { ... }`

Comment: My point is the regex does not match; both `/?s=` and any search string, i.e. `/?s=example` are matched and returned in the if statement, and returned 'else' with `!regex.test(url)`

Comment: I am not sure why it does not work for you. Did you run above code snippet? `https://example.com/?s=` returns true, and `https://example.com/?s=withsearchterms` returns false. Usage in an `if` statement: `if(regex.test(url)) { /* match */ } else { /* no match */}`

Comment: Yes, I ran the snippet that's now in my edited question.

Comment: Indeed, input string `'http://example.com/search/?s='` is always a match. Input string `'http://example.com/search/?s=foo'` is not.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative that (mostly) avoids regular expressions:

```
function isEmptySearch(urlString) {
    const url = new URL(urlString);
    const urlParams = url.search.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&').reduce( (acc, cur) => {
        const param = cur.split('=');
        acc[param[0]] = param[1];
        return acc;
    }, {});
    return !urlParams.s;
}

const testUrls = [
    "http://example.com/search/",
    "http://example.com/search/?s=",
    "http://example.com/search/?s=&foo=bar&baz",
    "http://example.com/search/?s=hello&foo=bar&baz"
];
testUrls.forEach( url => console.log(`${url}: empty search = ${isEmptySearch(url)}`) );
```

I think I prefer the regex option presented earlier by Peter Thoeny as it's less verbose, but this version might be of interest.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting; I'll take a look at this. I can't see what seems to be wrong with Peter's RegEx.

Answer (score 2):

If You want to use REGEX, you could use `exec()` instead of `test()` because the test function isn't good at the case.
Try this:

```js
//URL-input
var href1 = 'http://example.com/?s='
var href2 = 'http://example.com/?s=xx'
var href3 = 'http://example.com/'

function alertsSearchString( href ){
  var regex = /(?<=\/\?s=).*$/
  var Container= regex.exec( href )
  if ( Container!=null && Container[0]=='' )
      alert( 'The search string is an empty string!' )
  else if (Container!=null)
      alert( 'The search string: ' + Container[0] )
  else 
      alert( "The Container is "
              + Container 
              +", because input URL isn't matched the \nREGEX :   "
              + regex.toString() )
}

//alerts-output
alertsSearchString( href1 )
alertsSearchString( href2 )
alertsSearchString( href3 )
```

**Output:**

```
First Alert : The search string is an empty string!
SecondAlert : The search string: xx
Third Alert : The Container is null because input URL isn't matched the 
              REGEX : /(?<=\/\?s=).*$/
```

**Detail:**

Regex expression: `(?<=\/\?s=).*$`

- `(?<=\/\?s=)` use lookbehind to check and skip `/?s=`.
- `.*` match zero to more characters after `/?s=`.
- `$` preceding text must occur at the end.

See [regex-demo](https://regexr.com/5h15v)

The source below is an edited from your example **Edit 11/22/2020** using `exec()`

```js
var search = 'http://example.com/search/?s='
var regex = /(?<=\/\?s=).*$/
    
var result=regex.exec( search )

if (result && result[0]=='') {
      
  alert("The search terms are empty.");
      
} else {

  alert("The search terms are not empty or no matched.");

}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's interesting/. How would I use exec() and your regex in my question edit example on 11/22/2020?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I edited my post. You can access the matched value of the object returned by `exec()` as `object[0]`. Specifically, `exec()` returns and assign to `result` in the source. To avoid access null, I've checked it is not null before empty checking as `result && result[0]==''`.

Comment: Thanks, but how does this check the URL in the browser window? Don't we need `window.location.href;` as in my original example? I'm still getting "The search terms are empty" with `http://example.com/search/?s=` and `http://example.com/search/?s=testme` and `http://example.com/search/`

Comment: Ah, my mistake; `var search = window.location.href;` works.

Answer (score 0):

Forget regex, nodejs `URL` is your friend. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/url.html#url_new_url_input_base

for legacy nodejs versions you can use `url.parse` and `querystring.parse`

```
const { URL } = require('url');
const url1 = new URL('https://example.com/?s=');
const url2 = new URL('https://example.com/?s=withsearchterms');

function hasEmptyQuery(u) {
  return [...u.searchParams]
    .some(([key, value]) => value.length === 0);
}

console.log(hasEmptyQuery(url1));
// true

console.log(hasEmptyQuery(url2));
// false
```

Comment: Thanks, but Node is far too large a library for a static Hugo site.

Comment: didn't realize this was in the browser... Thought you were in nodejs server side

Comment: Yes, it's browser side; I just can't figure out why the RegEx matches all URLs instead of a URL with `?s=` at the end. Is there a way to use jQuery?

Comment: Actually looks like `URL` is pretty well supported in browsers already. Check this out it may work for you as is. https://caniuse.com/?search=URL

Comment: Hmmm, that's an idea. But I don't see a RegEx as part of that API.

Comment: my idea was basically to ditch regex and parse using the `URL` module then you can filter based on the searchParams like the example above